# Single Producer/Multiple Consumers in Node

Tags: node.js

I've done my best to contrive an example of the problem I'm trying to simplify. I have a pool of workers, and each worker can do several tasks at a time. Each task takes an unspecified amount of time. The goal is to drain the task queue by keeping each each worker as busy as possible.

In order to accomplish this, once the taskQueue has a nonzero number of tasks, each Worker is given tasks up to maxTasks. When a worker completes any one task, he uses the callback he was given to return the result. The worker is then assigned a new task in that callback. Workers are continually given new tasks untilthe taskQueue is empty..

This doesn't feel like an elegant solution. Would this be better accomplished using a stream or an event emitter? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

````
function WorkerPool(numWorkers) {
  const workers = [];
  const taskQueue = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numWorkers; i += 1) {
    workers.push(Worker());
  }

  function supplyNewTask(worker) {
    if (taskQueue.length) {
      const task = taskQueue.pop();
      console.log(`task queue length decremented to ${taskQueue.length}`);
      worker.work(task, supplyNewTask);
    }
  }

  return {
    work: function(task) {
      for (const worker of workers) {
        if (worker.availableTasks()) {
          worker.work(task, supplyNewTask);
          return;
        }
      }
      
      // if couldn't find a buyer...
      taskQueue.push(task);
      console.log(`task queue length incremented to ${taskQueue.length}`);
    }
  }
}

function Worker() {
  let activeTasks = 0;
  let maxTasks = 5;

  return {
    availableTasks: () => maxTasks - activeTasks,
    work: function(task, callback) {
      activeTasks += 1;
      console.log(`workers active tasks incremented to ${activeTasks}`);

      // do some work that takes an unspecified 
      // amount of time, then callback with the 
      // result.
      setTimeout(() => {
        activeTasks -= 1;
        console.log(`workers active tasks decremented to ${activeTasks}`);
        callback(this);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    },
  };
}


const pool = WorkerPool(3);
for (let i = 0; i < 6000; i++) {
  pool.work({ /* some work to be done */ });
}
```
````